# Why does using an index for a list return a "None Type not sub-scriptable error"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, median, nonetype

I wrote a program that returns the median of a list of input. It takes in two inputs.
First Input = number of elements
Second input = elements

```
numElements = int(input())
elements = [int(num) for num in input().split(' ')]
elements = elements.sort()
if numElements % 2 == 0:
    medianOne = (numElements / 2) -1
    median = (elements[medianOne] + elements[medianOne + 1])/2
    print(median)
else:
    medianIndex = round(((float(numElements)/2)+0.2)) - 1
    median = elements[medianIndex]
    print(median)
```

When I supply an odd number of elements, I get a NoneType not subscriptable error. Why is this?

Comment: `elements.sort()` is returning None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elements.sort() sorts the list in place.
sorted(elements) returns a sorted array.

That was the problem.

Comment: Please, select the answer as the correct one!!

Comment: I have to wait 2 more days in order to do that.